# JavaScript: how to open same same file location; finding absolute filenames

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html button that when clicked "`onclick=`" activates the following script.

`<script>
    window.open("/");
</script>`

This opens the index.html file at the root directory.
This would be all that I need, but I need a way to open the current file regardless of its current path; I should be able to run the script and expect it to refresh even if the file was downloaded. Is this even possible, can I fetch the current file directory using JS?

*I'm not trying to simply refresh the page.*

ex:

example.html

When I run the script, it should automatically open `example.html`

If `example.html` is at `exampleweb.org/` then it should open `exampleweb.org/example.html`, if I download it on a windows computer and it's at `C/.../downloads/` then when I run the script it will open the file located at `C:/.../downloads/example.html`.

Comment: Are you trying to use `window.open` to open a file on someones desktop? Example: `window.open('/users/myfile.csv')`?

Comment: @mwilson If it were downloaded, yes. Otherwise I just need my html to run correctly even if it's no longer at the root directory of the website, which is where it's currently at. I'm tryin to make the file itself.

Comment: think about your question.  Would you really like someone to be able to see your file directory on your client side computer when you visit their webpage?  No, you can't do that.  If the file is small enough you may be able to save it in local storage and you can get access to that

Comment: @DCR So what I'm getting is that this can't be done?

Comment: i'm not 100% clear on what you are asking. If you are asking can you see someone's c drive then then answer is definitely no

Comment: @DCR I'm trying to make the file find the current file path of the current file, regardless of whether it's downloaded or not. Added a vague example above.

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense. I don't understand what you are asking.